# Solving a system of second order tightly coupled nonlinear ODE with six initial conditions in Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system, computational-mathematics

I am solving a problem from fluid dynamics; in particular tightly coupled nonlinear ordinary differential equations. The following is a scaled-down version of my actual problem.

I have solved system of coupled odes many times in the past but this case is different since double derivatives of one variable depends on the double derivative of another variable.

How do I implement it in $ode45$? I need $3$ x $2  = 6$ plots of $x$, $x-dot$ and $x-ddot$ versus time for $t$, $0$ to $2$. All required initial conditions have zero values.

https://postimg.cc/0zf8XV9x

Any help will be highly appreciated.
If the ODEs had no last terms of double derivatives, I would have done it myself.

Comment: Are you familiar with the process of reducing the order of a second order system of ODE's to produce a system of first order ODE's with twice as many equations?

Comment: Yes, I am. For me the issue is how to take care of the updated values of the double derivatives after the first loop is done. My concern is how to implement with ode45 in Matlab. If you could help me with this, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: You do not need to keep those derivatives between different function calls. You can compute that directly from the current state. If taking values from the past is explicitly required by the physical model, you will need to use a DDE solver for the delay-differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Your system linked to in the question,
\begin{align}
\ddot x_1&=t^2x_1\sin(4\pi t)-x_2^2-\dot x_1x_2t+\dot x_2t+\ddot x_2\\
\ddot x_2&=t^2x_2\sin(4\pi t)-x_1^2+\dot x_1x_2t+\dot x_1t-\ddot x_1
\end{align}
is just a linear system for the second derivatives, with constant system matrix and the right side depending on the values and first derivatives. In the example
$$
\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}\pmatrix{\ddot x_1\\\ddot x_2}=\pmatrix{t^2x_1\sin(4\pi t)-x_2^2-\dot x_1x_2t+\dot x_2t\\t^2x_2\sin(4\pi t)-x_1^2+\dot x_1x_2t+\dot x_1t}.
$$
Construct the matrix, or get it as global constant, construct the right side, and solve the system with one of the provided linear solvers.

```
def odefun(t, u):
    x1, x2, dotx1, dotx2 = u
    A = np.array([[1,-1],[1,1]]);
    s = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)*t**2
    b = np.array([ 
         s*x_1-x_2**2-dotx1*x2*t+dotx2*t, 
         s*x_2-x_2**2+dotx2*x1*t+dotx1*t
    ])
    dot2x = np.linalg.solve(A,b);
    return [ dotx1, dotx2, dot2x[0], dot2x[1] ]
```

With the matlab solvers, you can this even leave un-solved and provide the system matrix of the full sytem
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&-1&1}
\pmatrix{\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\\\ddot x_1\\\ddot x_2}
=
\pmatrix{\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\\b_1(t,x_1,x_2,\dot x_1,\dot x_2)\\b_2(t,x_1,x_2,\dot x_1,\dot x_2)}.
$$
as the weight/mass matrix parameter.

---

The modified system that you produced in the comments,
\begin{align}
\ddot x_1&=tx_2-x_1\dot x_2-\ddot x_2\\
\ddot x_2&=t^2x_1+x_2\dot x_1-\ddot x_1
\end{align}
looks more simple but is in fact more complicated as it is singular in the higher order derivatives. Indeed, one can replace the second equation be the difference of both to get
\begin{align}
\ddot x_1+\ddot x_2&=tx_2-x_1\dot x_2\\
0&=t^2x_1-tx_2+x_2\dot x_1+x_1\dot x_2
\end{align}
This can be solved into an explicit first order system by introducing the state vector $(x_1,x_2,u)$ with the intended relation $u=\dot x_1+\dot x_2$ so that
\begin{align}
\dot x_1&=\frac{t^2x_1-tx_2+ux_1}{x_1-x_2},\\
\dot x_2&=\frac{t^2x_1-tx_2+ux_2}{x_2-x_1},\\
\dot u&=tx_2-x_1\frac{t^2x_1-tx_2+ux_2}{x_2-x_1}
   =\frac{tx_2^2-t^2x_1^2-ux_1x_2}{x_2-x_1}.
\end{align}
An actual implementation could re-use intermediary expressions like the value of $\dot x_2$.

Comment: @ Lutzl, Can we talk in person on another forum to discuss this problem? Or can you please help me with the solution of a much simpler problem: https://postimg.cc/9z7LXg8B

Comment: That problem is a DAE, the highest order terms are $\ddot x_1+\ddot x_2$ in both equations. The difference of the equation has leading order terms $x_1\dot x_2+\dot x_1x_2$. Set $u=\dot x_1+\dot x_2$ and eliminate $\dot x_2$ for $u$, and so on. -- Why do you insist on leaving the second derivatives on the right side? Put them all to the left to get a better idea about the system.

Comment: The delay is not important for me. How do I store the updated value of the double derivatives as the ode45 code runs? The way ode45 works, I get x and x-dot as output but not the double derivatives.

Comment: If you know $x$ and $\dot x$, then you can just recompute $\ddot x$ as the second half of the value of the ODE function, as that is defined as $(\dot x,\ddot x)=f(t,(x,\dot x))$. In Matlab the ODE solver has a variant of its return values that includes the derivatives at the returned sample points, see docu.

Comment: I have fresh update for this problem. can you please have a look at it CAREFULLY. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/429363-how-to-implement-tightly-coupled-nonlinear-odes-using-ode45-in-matlab?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view#comment_636071

Comment: I still do not understand your thinking blockade in bringing all the highest order derivatives to the left side of the equation. Linear and non-linear solvers exist to turn implicitly given values into explicit values (or approximations thereof). There is no reason to introduce a Gauß-Seidel iteration (and that without caring about convergence) that runs alongside and askew the ODE integration.

Comment: Or in short, you keep asking "How can I do it" and I keep repeating "You should not do this, it is a bad idea, there is an easily implemented better way to get exactly what is necessary without any hokuspokus that goes outside of the specifications of the packages used."

Comment: In the code in the matlab forum, what you are actually solving is $\dot y_3=y_3$ and $\dot y_6=y_6$, with the obvious exponential solutions $y_3(t)=y_3(0)e^t$ and $y_6(t)=y_6(0)e^t$. This is most likely not what you wanted to achieve. You should also recognize that the purported second derivative does in no way reflect the maxima and minima of the first derivative, against the fundamental insights of calculus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85644/discussion-between-vikash-and-lutzl).

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you all so much for helping me fix this problem. :)